# Not showing updated apk in play Store

Tags: android

i have upload update apk to play store, but on search in play store not showing.

and one more if try to check in web play store date is updated but while downloading, its downloading previews version.

all ready 12 hours over.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait at least 30min - 1hour in order to see the changes in the PlayStore.

Check if the PlayConsole, go to your app,  Release Management , and check if your last version is Full rollout  [image: PlayConsole]

Comment: answer updated, would be fine if you add a screenshot of your production track in your question

Comment: you check screenshot

Comment: and what is the version you download from playstore?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes more time ,Once our app took two days so what you can do is just wait it will get updated automatically

Comment: I think this is not an answer you can just add a comment on the question